# Multiple SPI Busses in Ribbon Cable

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, spi, digital-communications

I have a multiple SPI busses running through a ribbon cable which is 15cm long. What is the best CS, SCK, MOSI, MISO orientation to avoid the cross talk between each wire and is it enough to use ground wire separation between each SPI connection pair?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I would place a bounty on this if I could. Looking forward to answers from the masters :)

Comment: What is the frequency of your SPI buses ?

Comment: its about 10MHz

Comment: given the length, and these are unidirectional signals, suggest using a Schmitt trigger buffer at receiving end, to clean up ringing due to cable inductance.

Answer (score 2):

Following the logic of SPI work---with your goal, terms, and conditions---you can try this:

1. GND
2. SCK  - transits during a whole cycle, place it between two GNDs for good
3. NPCS - this signal is driven low (push-pull or open-drain) when active, i.e. "equals" to GND
4. MOSI or MISO - typically, when MOSI is active, MISO is inactive ...
5. MISO or MOSI - ... and vise versa (only one - MISO or MOSI - is active a time)
6. GND

and so on...

But, IMO, the real effect of such combining would be questionable. The proven path is to use every second wire in a ribbon cable as GND, such as [Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds097.pdf), [Altera](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_bbii.pdf), ARM partners like Segger do.

Also, remember that at high frequencies:

1. a VCC could be considered as GND because there are decoupling caps between
2. a static signal like NPCS could be considered as VCC or GND because it's driven to one of them
3. a signal could be considered as static (or background) if it has no transitions while others have

Good luck.